# Conditional Components in Modelica

Tags: modelica, dymola, openmodelica

I want with conditional expressions reduce large general models with over 300000 equations so that only a relevant part remains.
To illustrate the problem I have the following minimal model:

```
model Test
  parameter Boolean level1=true;
  parameter Boolean level2=false;
  Integer x=1 if level1;
  Integer y=2 if level2;
  Integer z;
equation
  if level1 and level2 then
    z = x+y;
  elseif level1 then
    z = x;
  elseif level2 then
    z = y;
  else
    z=0;
  end if;
end Test;
```

This model does not work in Dymola,
with the error message:

> Undeclared variables: y since the declaration of y was conditionally
>   removed

In OpenModelica the model works. **So my question is, is this Model Modelica compliant?**
In the Modelica 3.4 specification section 4.4.5 I did not find anything that would invalidate this model.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, since `y` and `x` are declared conditional and 4.4.5 includes the statement "A component declared with a condition-attribute can only be modified and/or used in connections".

There is no special rule that they can be removed from branches of if-statements.